# ReactNative Firebase Cloud Messaging Error

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using below plugin to implement cloud messaging.
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/tree/master/packages/messaging

Unfortunately, this plugin updated recently and they didn't release new documentation.
https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/messaging

Before, I used to use below code inside AppDelegate but now I can't sure how could I use new class RNFBMessaging...

> [RNFirebaseNotifications configure];
>
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary *)options {
>     return [[LineSDKLogin sharedInstance] handleOpenURL:url]; }
> - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
>     [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance]
>     didReceiveLocalNotification:notification]; }
> - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo
>     fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void
>     (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
>     [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance]
>     didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo
>     fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler]; }
> - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings
>     *)notificationSettings {   [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings]; }

I believe someone already implemented this new version of plugin ...
Please help me...

Comment: If you have any issues with the package version upgrade, open an issue in the GitHub, I think it's more helpful !

Comment: Shall I have to use v5 still now...?